# Relay-type automatic voltage regulator (AVR) switching interruption

Tags: voltage-regulator, switching

I want to build a relay-type automatic voltage regulator (AVR), but one thing is bothering me.

Based on what I found, a relay switches to select a desired voltage, therefore there will be some interruption during the time of switching.

How do commercial relay-type AVRs deal with the interruption during switching?

Answer (score 0):

Transformer tap changing is done at very high power at substations. Resistors are temporarily switched in with extra contacts to absorb the inductive energy and allow uninterrupted on load operation. The energy wasted in the resistors is low but the peak power is high.

Comment: Based on ITI Curve 20ms is maximum limit for 0V, maybe i should select a relay faster than that.